# What is the original intentional use of the phrase 'systems thinking'?

Tags: phrases, phrase-usage, phrase-origin

I have found references in 1963 which seem to be the 'first published that google knows about', but it seems from this that the phrase was in fairly common use by then:see [here](https://books.google.rs/books?id=_P10IM5ffIoC&pg=PA3180&dq=%22%22systems%20thinking%22%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi4z_DpuofwAhVQtIsKHWymD_EQ6AEwBHoECAYQAg#v=onepage&q=%22systems%20thinking%22&f=false)
and [here](https://books.google.rs/books?id=KPAmAQAAIAAJ&pg=RA4-PA37&dq=%22%22systems%20thinking%22%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi4z_DpuofwAhVQtIsKHWymD_EQ6AEwAHoECAEQAg#v=onepage&q=%22systems%20thinking%22&f=false).

(see my research at [stream.syscoi.com](https://stream.syscoi.com/2021/04/18/a-fools-quest-for-the-first-use-of-the-phrase-systems-thinking/))

Comment: 1947 https://books.google.com/books?id=SNJEAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA1253&dq=%22systems+thinking%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjS-velkojwAhVVnJ4KHYtvAooQ6AEwAHoECAIQAg

Comment: 1943 https://www.google.com/books/edition/Educational_Leadership/SFwbAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22systems+thinking%22&dq=%22systems+thinking%22&printsec=frontcover